# Change text on a symbol in Flash 

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I'm trying to change the text on several symbols by having a user press one designated symbol !  I don't care if its with flash 2.0 or 3.0 , I did a menu bar and want to change the text on the symbols if on symbol in particular is pressed ! I tried everything I could think of and expected it to be fairly easy ! I must be missing something !

When a user presses a symbol code is executed to change the text on all the other buttons !

There must be more than my_symbol.text="text I want";
Is there a sub_scene.scene.instance_name.text or something I'm missing ?

Thanks

Pete

Comment: can you post some code so that we can help you further?

Comment: I've tried coding in 2.0 and 3.0 , such as this in 3.0.  

The menu buttons are movie clips with one button used to toggle language without reloading the page .  


lang.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonclick);

function onButtonclick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 home_mc.text = "new language ";
}

Comment: Sorry for the delay , had it take an unexpected trip ! 

Thanks , it works fine for a movie clip but not for a button , is there another way to also do it for a button symbol ? 

Thanks again 

Pete

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite vague but you need to target the textField and not the symbol in any case:

```
myMovieClip.myTextField.text = "Changed"
```

If this is not working first thing to check is if the instance of the container is accessible from your scripts own scope :

```
trace(myMovieClip);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and let you know 
! 

Pete

Comment: preliminary test shows it should work fine with what you suggested . Thanks 

Pete